# Несколько изображений в одном сообщении, telegram bot api

Tags: php, telegram-bot, telegram

Возможно ли отправить несколько изображений в 1 сообщении с помощью telegram bot api, php? Я знаю о методе sendPhoto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать метод sendMediaGroup

https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmediagroup

Answer (score 0):

Вот самый хороший, и работающий пример отправки:

```
function sendTelegram($method, $response) {
  $ch = curl_init('https://api.telegram.org/bot' . TOKEN . '/' . $method);  
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);  
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $response);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
  $res = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $res;
}

sendTelegram (
  'sendMediaGroup',
  array (
    'chat_id' => $data['message']['chat']['id'],
    'media' => json_encode([
        ['type' => 'photo', 'media' => 'attach://1.jpg', 'caption' => 'step 1' ],
        ['type' => 'photo', 'media' => 'attach://2.jpg', 'caption' => 'step 2' ],
    ]),
    '1.jpg' => curl_file_create(realpath('1.jpg')),
    '2.jpg' => curl_file_create(realpath('2.jpg'))
  )
);
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]