# Как научить юзер-бот группировать вложения в альбом при пересылке сообщений из канала в канала в телеграме с библиотекой telethon python

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

Вот код:

```
client = TelegramClient('anon', API_ID, API_HASH)

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=CHANNELS))
async def main(event):
await client.send_message(MY_CHANNEL_ID, event.message)

client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()
with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

В таком варианте, при пересылке сообщения с множеством вложений разбиваются на отдельные сообщения, а нужно, чтобы пересылался альбом+текст.

Comment: [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/867899/178576)?

Comment: учитывая, что я новичок в этой теме, возможно, это и рабочий метод, но я не знаю, как его применить к моему коду, поэтому меня интересует тоже самое только на питоне.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если сообщение является группой нескольких сообщений (альбом из фото или видео), у всех этих сообщений будет одно и то же значение атрибута `grouped_id`.
Если же сообщение не альбом, например, одно изображение, или одно видео, значением атрибута `grouped_id` будет `None`. Вы можете использовать это как проверку.

Сами альбомы можно обрабатывать с помощью специального декоратора `events.Album`.

```
# Декоратор который обрабатывает альбомы c указанных каналов
@client.on(events.Album(chats=CHANNELS)) 
async def new_album(event):
    await client.send_message(
        entity=MY_CHANNEL_ID, # Канал на который перешлется сообщение
        file=event.messages, # Список сообщений (изображений) из альбома
        message=event.text, # Текст сообщения
    )
```

Comment: Благодарю вас! Ваш ответ мне помог!

Comment: @Ousha Если мой ответ вам помог, оцените его как верный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer